# removing url params with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following ajaxError

```
$(document).ajaxError(function (e, xhr, settings) {
   if ( settings.url == "/users/sign_in" ) {
        if (xhr.status == 401) {
           $('#notice_signin').html(xhr.responseText);
           $('#notice_signin').addClass("alert").addClass("alert-error");
        }
      }
});
```

the thing is that settings.url has different params such as locale, source, etc.. so `settings.url` never matches `/users/sign_in` but is `/users/sign_in?lang=fr&source=fb`

what is an easy way to strip the params?

Comment: What is the purpose of stripping?

Comment: so that settings.url will be `/users/sign_in` and not `/users/sign_in?lang=fr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need it only to check the url you can use [indexOf](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) method

```
if ( settings.url.toLowerCase().indexOf("/users/sign_in")>-1)
....
```

Otherwise if you want to have the url withouth parameters for later usage you can use [split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) method

```
var url = settings.url.split('?')[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (settings.url.split('?')[0] == '/users/sign_in') {
   ...
}
```

Note that this doesn't include error handling in case `settings.url` happens to be `null`.

As a side note, if '/users/sign_in' is the path of the current page, you might instead use `window.location.pathname` instead of hardcoding the value.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try using `split`

```
var urlString = '/users/sign_in?lang=fr&source=fb';
var urlArray =  urlString.split('?');
alert(urlArray[0]);
var settingsurl = urlArray[0];


if ( settings.url == "/users/sign_in" ) {
       ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or another option can use `substring`

```
if ( settings.url.substr(0,settings.url.indexOf("?")) == "/users/sign_in" )
```